# building a map using slam_gmapping

Tags: slam, navigation, gmapping, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and indigo version.

Also, I used kinect and custom made robot with encoders.

I published laser scan, odom, and tf information and now I'm starting building the map but I faced some problems

This the launch file for publishing laser scan information:

```
<launch>    
  <arg name="camera" default="camera"/>     
  <include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch">   
  <arg name="camera" default="$(arg camera)"/>  
  </include>    
  <node pkg="pointcloud_to_laserscan" type="pointcloud_to_laserscan_node" name="pointcloud_to_laserscan">   
  <remap from="cloud_in" to="/camera/depth/points"/>    
  </node>   
</launch>
```

And I can view the laser scans successfully in rviz.

This is the node to publish odom information (the nodes assumes the robot is moving in circle):

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "odometry_publisher");

  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Publisher odom_pub = n.advertise<nav_msgs::Odometry>("odom", 50);
  tf::TransformBroadcaster odom_broadcaster;

  double x = 0.0;
  double y = 0.0;
  double th = 0.0;

  double vx = 0.1;
  double vy = -0.1;
  double vth = 0.1;

  ros::Time current_time, last_time;
  current_time = ros::Time::now();
  last_time = ros::Time::now();

  ros::Rate r(1.0);
  while(n.ok()){

    ros::spinOnce();               // check for incoming messages
    current_time = ros::Time::now();

    //compute odometry in a typical way given the velocities of the robot
    double dt = (current_time - last_time).toSec();
    double delta_x = (vx * cos(th) - vy * sin(th)) * dt;
    double delta_y = (vx * sin(th) + vy * cos(th)) * dt;
    double delta_th = vth * dt;

    x += delta_x;
    y += delta_y;
    th += delta_th;

    //since all odometry is 6DOF we'll need a quaternion created from yaw
    geometry_msgs::Quaternion odom_quat = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(th);

    //first, we'll publish the transform over tf
    geometry_msgs::TransformStamped odom_trans;
    odom_trans.header.stamp = current_time;
    odom_trans.header.frame_id = "odom";
    odom_trans.child_frame_id = "base_link";

    odom_trans.transform.translation.x = x;
    odom_trans.transform.translation.y = y;
    odom_trans.transform.translation.z = 0.0;
    odom_trans.transform.rotation = odom_quat;

    //send the transform
    odom_broadcaster.sendTransform(odom_trans);

    //next, we'll publish the odometry message over ROS
    nav_msgs::Odometry odom;
    odom.header.stamp = current_time;
    odom.header.frame_id = "odom";

    //set the position
    odom.pose.pose.position.x = x;
    odom.pose.pose.position.y = y;
    odom.pose.pose.position.z = 0.0;
    odom.pose.pose.orientation = odom_quat;

    //set the velocity
    odom.child_frame_id = "base_link";
    odom.twist.twist.linear.x = vx;
    odom.twist.twist.linear.y = vy;
    odom.twist.twist.angular.z = vth;

    //publish the message
    odom_pub.publish(odom);

    last_time = current_time;
    r.sleep();
  }
}
```

I followed the steps in this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData#record)

When I reached this command : `rosbag play --clock mylaserdata.bag` the other terminal gives this error:

```
Warning: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame base_laser at time 1.4273e+09 according to authority unknown_publisher
Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained
         at line 260 in /tmp/buildd/ros-indigo-tf2-0.5.7-0trusty-20141230-0040/src/buffer_core.cpp
```

Also, after typing this command: `rosrun map_server map_saver` it says `Waiting for the map` and didn't do any thing.

UPDATE:

I used robot_state_publisher package to publish the TF

and this is the TF of the robot:
[image: TF]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205872/building-a-map-using-slam_gmapping/) by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear nouf,

did you remember to set use_sim_time param to true?

```
rosparam set use_sim_time true
```

Please note that your odometry publisher node has a problem in main loop:

```
ros::spinOnce();       

[...]

odom_broadcaster.sendTransform(odom_trans);

[...]

odom_pub.publish(odom);

r.sleep();
```

Following execution flow you:

- broadcast tf;
- publish odom topic;
- wait for rate;
- invoke ros::spinOnce().

I remember you that tf and topics are not really published until you invoke ros::spinOnce(): so, basically, you are publishing this information with one second delay. I suggest you to move ros::spinOnce() just after odom topic publisher line.

Hope this help...

### UPDATE

First: I suggest you to modify your code in order to have tf published in right way. Further more you are broadcasting odom -> base_link transformation with at 1Hz rate and base_link -> base_laser transformation at 100Hz and this is not a good practice. I cannot tell you that this will fix your problem but you should fix them before go on.

Second: run

```
rosrun tf view_frames
```

and

```
roswtf
```

The first will create a PDF contains the tf tree pf your robot: you can us it in order to be sure tf chain is not broken. The second will start some automatic diagnostic tool in order to check your transformation health status.

### UPDATE

Sorry for late reply.... there a lot of inconsistence in your tf tree:

- map -> odom transformation is missing. This should be provided by gmapping so if it was not running when you get view frames this is ok;
- posted log refer to a base_laser frame but in your tf tree you named it laser_link (I assume both them refer to laser frame of course :-) );
- base_link -> camera_link transformation is missing. If should be provided by robot_state_publisher too.

Try to fix those issues. Can you also post output from roswtf?

---

Originally posted by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) with karma: 497 on 2015-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on 2015-03-27**:
Yes I did set use_sim_time to true. and thank you for your suggestion. Although I think there is problem somewhere in TF. I think I missed something because I really got confused reading about it. I read all the tutorials and explanations in wiki.ros but I didn't get full understanding!

**Comment by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on 2015-03-27**:
May you please explain in brief what should I do in steps regarding TF? Thank you

**Comment by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on 2015-03-28**:
May you please see the update?